# Unable to change background color of Frame widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Python and Tkinter to create a game, and I'm attempting to have different "screens" (main menu and a level editor so far) which are each a `tkinter.Frame` object, and in the class definition for the main menu screen (`ScreenMainMenu`), in `__init__`, on line 11, I'm attempting to use `self.config()` in order to change the width, height, and background color of the "main menu" `tkinter.Frame`. But when I run this code, the background is still grey. I'm guessing I am missing something obvious (I am still fairly new to Tkinter and classes). Any help would be much appreciated - thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH = {"MainMenu": 600, "Editor": 450}
HEIGHT = {"MainMenu": 500, "Editor": 501}

class ScreenMainMenu(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    parent.parent.geometry("{}x{}".format(WIDTH["MainMenu"], HEIGHT["MainMenu"]))
    parent.config(width=WIDTH["MainMenu"], height=HEIGHT["MainMenu"])
    self.config(width=WIDTH["MainMenu"], height=HEIGHT["MainMenu"], background="red")
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

  def create_widgets(self):
  #  self.logo = tk.Label(self, image=r"res\logo.png")
    self.logo = tk.Label(self, text="Build The Galaxy")
    self.button_new_game = tk.Button(self, text="New Game")
    self.button_load_game = tk.Button(self, text="Load Game")
    self.button_editor = tk.Button(self, text="Editor")
    self.button_exit = tk.Button(self, text="Exit")

    self.logo.grid(sticky="EW")
    self.button_new_game.grid(row=1, sticky="EW")
    self.button_load_game.grid(row=2, sticky="EW")
    self.button_editor.grid(row=3, sticky="EW")
    self.button_exit.grid(row=4, sticky="EW")

class ScreenEditor(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.grid()
    parent.parent.geometry("{}x{}".format(WIDTH["Editor"], HEIGHT["Editor"]))

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.parent = parent
    self.grid()
    self.screen_open_main_menu()

  def screen_open_main_menu(self):
    self.screen_mainmenu = ScreenMainMenu(self)

  def screen_open_editor(self):
    self.screen_editor = ScreenEditor(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  root.resizable(False, False)
  root.title("Build The Galaxy")
  main_app = MainApplication(root)
  root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tkinter, normally all widgets adjust their size to fit the contents. That means, your frame is actually red (or whatever), it just fits its content. (You can check it commenting out the self.create_widgets() method.) You can force the size with the .grid_propagate() method, passing a 0 as parameter:

```
class ScreenMainMenu(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    parent.parent.geometry("{}x{}".format(WIDTH["MainMenu"], HEIGHT["MainMenu"]))
    parent.config(width=WIDTH["MainMenu"], height=HEIGHT["MainMenu"])
    self.config(width=WIDTH["MainMenu"], height=HEIGHT["MainMenu"], background="red")
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()
    self.grid_propagate(0)  # force the widget to a certain size
```

BTW, you can use super() to initialize the parent:

```
super().__init__(parent)  # yes, without self!
```